Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'clientID'
I'm trying to set my client ID for Google Sign-In by assigning it to 'GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"', but I'm encountering an error stating 'Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'clientID'. I already install the pod 'GoogleSignIn'. How can I resolve this? My goal is to enable Google authentication for Firebase login.
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import GoogleSignIn

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication. LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = "MY Client ID" // Error : Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'clientID'
    return true
  }
}


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

To add to Doug's comment, you only needed 1 line of code, that reported the error, or maybe 11 lines from the application method. Focusing on the code that gives the error, and avoiding distracting the reader with other code, facilitates a quick answer.

Thank you @DougStevenson  for your feedback!  This was my first question on Stack Overflow, and I'm not familiar with the best practices for asking questions.I appreciate the advice. I’ve edited my question to include the text and code directly, making it easier to read. Please let me know if there are any other improvements I can make.

You don't have to manually set the client ID to GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID. Instead, download the GoogleService-Info file from the Google console and add it to your project. This file includes both CLIENT_ID and REVERSED_CLIENT_ID. Could you please specify which version of the Google-SignIn SDK you're using?

The GoogleService-Info file is already included in my project. I'm using
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'

Oh sorry, you use an old version of Google sign-in SDK. maybe update the version if it's possible for you.

Great! It's working now. Thank you for your assistance. I'll update the Google sign-in SDK to the latest version.
